# How to prevent XamlWriter.Save from serializing the BaseUri property?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, serialization, xamlwriter

I'm making a theme editor for a WPF application. I generate XAML files dynamically, then I compile them into a DLL that is used by the application. The code used to generate the XAML files goes along those lines:

```
var dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
...

dictionary.Add(key, new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri(relativePath, UriKind.Relative) });
...

XamlWriter.Save(dictionary, "myDictionary.xaml");
```

My problem is that `XamlWriter.Save` also serializes the `BaseUri` property:

```
<BitmapImage BaseUri="{x:Null}" UriSource="Images\myImage.png" x:Key="myImage" />
```

The result is that when the application tries to fetch this image, it doesn't find it because `BaseUri` is not set. Normally the XAML parser sets this property (through the `IUriContext` interface), but when it is already set explicitly in XAML, the parser doesn't set it, so it remains null.

**Is there a way to prevent the `XamlWriter` from serializing the `BaseUri` property?**

If I was serializing a custom class, I could add a `ShouldSerializeBaseUri()` method, or implement `IUriContext` explicitly (I tried both options and they give the desired result), but how to do it for `BitmapImage`?

As a last resort, I could load the XAML file and remove the attribute with Linq to XML, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by generating the XAML manually with Linq to XML.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of preventing `XamlWriter` from writing `BaseUri` property we give it something that does not impact image loading? For example the following code:

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources/photo.JPG"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

seems to be equivalent to

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage BaseUri="pack://application:,," UriSource="Resources/photo.JPG"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Try

```
  dictionary.Add("Image", new BitmapImage{
    BaseUri=new Uri("pack://application:,,"),
    UriSource = new Uri(@"Images\myImage.png", UriKind.Relative)
  });
```

If you try to set image source to the BitmapImage created this way from the code - it won't work. But `XamlWriter.Save()` produces XAML that does work when it's XAML :). Well, worth trying I hope.