# Convert pack:// URI to relative URI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

During serialization with a `XamlWriter`, among other things I am trying to serialize `Image` controls. These `Source` property of these controls is set to a relative URI.

However, after serializing with the `XamlWriter`, the `Image` controls contain paths like this:

**Original Path**

```
../test.png
```

**XamlWriter Path**

```
pack://application:,,,/test.png
```

Is there any way to prevent the `XamlWriter` from changing relative paths to pack paths?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495253/how-to-prevent-xamlwriter-save-from-serializing-the-baseuri-property

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I came up with a workaround which I thought I'd share.

I created new class, `ImageData` to encapsulate the relative Uri which I needed to load into the `Image` control.

```
public class ImageData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Relative path to image
    /// </summary>
    public string ImageSourceUri { get; set; }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return new BitmapImage(App.GetPathUri(ImageSourceUri)); }
    }
}
```

Then I created a function in the `App` class (for convenience) to convert the relative path into an absolute Uri.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a relative path from the current directory to an absolute path 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="relativePath">Relative path from the current directory</param>
    public static string GetPath(string relativePath)
    {
        return System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, relativePath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a relative path from the current directory to an absolute Uri 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="relativePath">Relative path from the current directory</param>
    public static Uri GetPathUri(string relativePath)
    {
        return new Uri(GetPath(relativePath), UriKind.Absolute);
    }
```

Finally, I created a `DataTemplate` in XAML, again in the App.xaml file for convenience:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ImageData}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now when the `XamlWriter.Save` method is called, the XAML that is outputted looks like this:

```
<d:ImageData ImageSourceUri="test_local.png" />
```

So the paths get stored as relative paths, of type `string`, and then when the XAML is loaded in again using `XamlReader.Load`, the DataTemplate binds to the `ImageSource` property, which converts the relative path to an absolute one as late as possible.

Comment: As a side note, whether to place the GetPath logic in the App class or not is a design consideration - depending on the context it may reduce coupling to place it as a private method in the ImageData class..